# AngularJS change currency display by manipulating the $locale

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, currency, angular-filters

So I'm struggling with this issue for some time now and yet I couldn't find an answer.

Basically I've this:

```
const formattedCurrency = $filter('currency')(input);
```

This returns me something like this `$0.00` ($ seem to be the default angular curency `CURRENCY_SYM:"$"`)

What I want to achieve is to make this return not `$0.00`but a dynamic currency, for example `€0.00` or `£0.00`.

So let's assume that I have a html page with this text:

*I have $0.00*

If I do this:

```
this.$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = '€';
```

My page will instantly change into:

*I have €0.00*

This is great, but the problem is that I get the currency sign from a promise, like this:

```
this.getUserCurrency(this.id).then((currency) => {
    $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = currency; // this does not work
});
```

And the problem is that the above is not working, it doesn't change my HTML page **even though my $locale was changed**.

My conclusion after my investigations by now is:

If I change the $locale currency it will automatically change all my currencies from my page, but if I do this inside an asynchronous function (promise), my locale will get changed but it won't affect the DOM anymore.

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you please try with 
function(error) {
      console.error(error)
 })
on your promise function

Comment: 1 sec i will reply. I was out but now I'm checking the answers

Comment: Any feedback m8?

Comment: Hello, I've given up on this since I have not received permissions to edit the child app, and since the answer did not gave me a solution for changing only the parent app. I upvoted your answer and probably many others will find it helpful and will upvote it also. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`$filter` in a AngularJS component & `$locale` are not parts of the digest cycle. In that way you are not be able to trigger a automatic `$scope` update by changing the `$locale` configuration object. In my opinion, its the best way to not use `$locale` as a part of your digest cycle (cause you are not able to do it that way).

You should persist your currency configuration in a global available variable or factory (which is a part of the digest cycle). You could use `$rootScope` to make your E2E binding work in a nice way. Also set your currency in `$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM` to proceed with this configuration in other code parts.

#### View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   {{ value | currency: $root.currencySymbol }}
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $filter, $locale, $http, $timeout) {

   $scope.value = 0.00;
   $rootScope.currencySymbol = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM;

   $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function (result) {
      $rootScope.currencySymbol = '€';
      $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = '€';
   });
});
```

**>> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vd8jgd0w/1/)**

---

### Same approach by using a factory:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   {{ value | currency: $root.currencyHandler.symbol }}
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function (
  $scope, 
  $rootScope, 
  $filter, 
  $locale, 
  $http, 
  $timeout,
  currencyHandler
  ) {

   $scope.value = 0.00;
   $rootScope.currencyHandler = currencyHandler;

   $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function (result) {
      currencyHandler.setCurrencySymbol('€');
   });
});

myApp.factory('currencyHandler', function ($locale) {
    return {
    symbol: $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM,
    setCurrencySymbol: function (value) {
      this.symbol = value;
        $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = value;
    }
  }
});
```

**>> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2cd46gq/)**

---

### An other approach by using `$watch` inside a `factory`:

In that way you are able to set `$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM` directly in your controller logic:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   {{ value | currency: $root.currencyHandler.symbol }}
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function (
  $scope, 
  $rootScope, 
  $filter, 
  $locale, 
  $http, 
  $timeout,
  currencyHandler
  ) {

   $scope.value = 0.00;
   $rootScope.currencyHandler = currencyHandler;

   $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function (result) {
      $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = '€'
   });
});

myApp.factory('currencyHandler', function ($locale, $rootScope) {

  let currencyHandler = {
    symbol: $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM
  };

  $rootScope.$watch(function () {
    return $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM;
  }, function (value) {
    currencyHandler.symbol = value;
  });

  return currencyHandler;
});
```

**>> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zotvhwht/)**

Comment: The thing is that I have to deal with 2 applications, the parent and the child app. In the child app I have the curency. In the parent app I have the $locale. The child app is imported into the parent via npm package. I am constrained to edit only the parent. So I can't change the child, meaning that I don't have access to the templates to edit this  {{ value | currency: $root.currencyHandler.symbol }}. Thats why I was forced to check a solution via $locale because If I change $locale in the parent app, the child app works without any change.

Comment: @paulalexandru I see. Sooo, there is no solution for this. You need to manually execute `$filter('currency')(input);` each time `$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM` changes.

Comment: Ok man, thank you for your help. I will rate up your answer and I will try to see if I can get an approval to make changes on the child app also.

Comment: @paulalexandru Glad to help ya. You may going to accept this answer? =)

Comment: To be honest I thought threre was an existing solution with the $locale thing. Currently I try to get permissions to change the child app and if I get and I manage to implement the code and it works I will yes.

Comment: @paulalexandru allright, good. Next time please provide all information about your application. In that way we are able to create a full qualified answer for you. Missing information like "2 applications" - "unable to access templates" are important limitations.

Comment: However, there is something strange. Changing $locale works if is not inside a promise.

Comment: @paulalexandru nope it doesnt trigger a digest cycle -> http://jsfiddle.net/occwg3ry/ it only work while set it up before the first digest cycle hits in. E.g. directly in your controller. -> http://jsfiddle.net/386weuLb/ But this only effects every `$locale` dependency which is used after this currency symbol "setter". It still does not trigger a digest cycle. =)

Comment: So isn't there a way to change the $locale dinamicaly? Found something here https://lgalfaso.github.io/angular-dynamic-locale/

Comment: @paulalexandru this will not help you because it uses the digest cycle like the solution I provided by using  `{{1000000 | currency}}`. Your code `$filter('currency')(input);` is not part of the digest cycle. So it will not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can force angularjs to refresh the $locale impact via `$state.reload()`.